# Restart option in Guess The Number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a hard time wiht this Guess The Number assignment. I can't seem to get it right and would like some help. The play again option isn't working because when you win the game and choose yes to play again it doesn't restart the game it continues on your next guess number (example: guess number 1, guess number 2...). But when you lose it goes back to the first part where it asks you "How many tries you would like". So how can I get the part where you win to do that? Also, can someone give me some tips on how to improve the hint option? Also, do I need to insert any of that *def main():* stuff? Because I'm not sure if we got to that point yet for this assignment. So please help me out. Thanks.

```
# This is a guess the number game.
import random
answer = "yes"
number = random.randint(1, 10)

while answer == 'yes':
    tries = 0
    guess = 0
    guessnumber = 0
    tries = int(input("How many tries would you like? "))
    tries2 = tries
    while guessnumber != tries2:
            guessnumber += 1
            guess = int(input("Enter guess number " + str(guessnumber) + ": "))
            if guess < number:
                print("You guessed too low")
                hint = input("Would you like a hint, yes or no?: ")
                if hint == "no":
                    continue
                    print("The number is less than", number + 1)
                if guess > number:
                    print("You guessed too high")
                    hint = input("Would you like a hint, yes or no?: ")
                    if hint == "no":
                        continue
                    print("The number is greater than", number - 1)
                if guess == number:
                    tries = str(tries)
                    print("YOU WON!")
                    answer = input("Play again? Yes/No? ") `enter code here`
                    if answer == 'no':
                        break
            if guess != number:
                number = str(number)
                print("GAME OVER!!! The number I was thinking of was " + number)
                answer = input("Play again? Yes/No? ")
                if answer == "no":
                    break
```

Comment: This is a little too close to "please correct my homework" for the site... can you distill this down to a minimal example that demonstrates the programming problem?

Comment: You only break the loop if they answer no. So if they say yes it just keeps looping.  Get the user's answer and break either way and let the condition of the loop handle the decision.
PS. He didn't ask anyone to write code for him just some help with his nested loops, no harm with that.

Comment: If I am asking for help "doing my homework" I ain't meaning too. I'm just trying to get some advice and tips to figure out how to do this. Also Jake what do you mean by that? Break when they say yes and no?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use functions. This is some possible pseudocode:

```
def game():
    tries = 0
    guess = 0
    ...
    if guess != number:
        number = str(number)
        print("GAME OVER!!! The number I was thinking of was " + number)

 answer = "yes"
 while answer == 'yes':
     game()
     answer = input("Play again? Yes/No? ")
```

Functions help to split problem to smaller and more maintainable parts.

For this code, for sure you can reset variables in code, but would not recommend doing it.

P.S. It is possible to understand what game it is, but better write description of if instead just writing "assignment". More clear question is, more likely you will get an answer.

Comment: The `break` is unnecessary. If `answer` is "no" the loop will terminate.

Comment: So I would put everything between def game(): and the answer = "yes"?

Comment: Tim comment is good. I updated code sample. ThatOneDude - answer = "yes" does not belong to "game"

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

random.randint(1, 1) is saying produce a random integer between 1 and 1. It always gives 1.

Why is there a copy of "tries" when it is only set once?

Indentation in Python MATTERS. It changes how if/elif/else branches are evaluated. So the (guess > number) and (guess == number) checks were conditional upon (guess < number) which is impossible. Given that these states: (guess < number), (guess > number) and (guess == number) are mutually exclusive and compares the same variables, its best to change the subsequent if blocks to elifs.

The "GAME OVER" should probably be trigger only after the tries have been exhausted, so it can't be inside the (guessnumber < tries) loop.

```
# This is a guess the number game.
import random
answer = "yes"
number = random.randint(1, 100)

while answer != 'no':
    guess = 0
    guessnumber = 0
    tries = int(input("How many tries would you like? "))
    while guessnumber < tries:
            guessnumber += 1
            guess = int(input("Enter guess number " + str(guessnumber) + ": "))
            if guess < number:
                print("You guessed too low")
                hint = input("Would you like a hint, yes or no?: ")
                if hint == "no":
                    continue
                print("The number is less than", number + 1)
            elif guess > number:
                print("You guessed too high")
                hint = input("Would you like a hint, yes or no?: ")
                if hint == "no":
                    continue
                print("The number is greater than", number - 1)
            elif guess == number:
                print("YOU WON!")
                answer = input("Play again? Yes/No? ") #enter code here
                break
    if (guess != number) and (guessnumber >= tries):
        number = str(number)
        print("GAME OVER!!! The number I was thinking of was " + number)
        answer = input("Play again? Yes/No? ")
```

Comment: Forgot to change the 1 back to 10 because I've been working on it all day my brain is bleh and I just put 1 to test it out. Also, so change the guess > number and guess == number to elif instead of if? And you know how I can make it restart when you play again after winning?

Comment: Its just good practice to use elif instead of if for associated conditions; in this instance, it won't change the program's behaviour.

Comment: I've edited the program. On the guess == number branch, you should unconditionally break because the repeat behaviour is governed by the outermost while loop checking for answer != 'no'.

Comment: So how do I unconditionally break? And is there a way I can make the guess == number part go out so it restarts to the "How many tries would you like?" part?

Comment: In the code above, an unconditional break is shown in the guess == number elif branch, as in it will always break if guess == number regardless of the user's answer. breaks apply to the current loop level, so that break statement applies to the "while guessnumber < tries" loop. When that break triggers, it will evaluate "if (guess != number) and (guessnumber >= tries)" which will be false, then it will loop in the outer loop "while answer != 'no'".

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks that makes sense :)